# How to make TaskList show exact time it took to complete a Task?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, mylyn, tasklist

Now it says `Created 2011-01-03 Completed 2011-01014`.

But I wonder how long this feature took(for how long was task activated in minutes/hours if possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try hoverring over the task in the Task List view.

In my Eclipse 3.5 installation, I see the total time that a feature was active (in hours:minutes) in a popup when hovering over the task in the Task List view.